# GHDL: file std_logic_1164.v93 has changed and must be reanalysed

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

Any ideas what's causing this error when compiling with ghdl vhdl simulator?

```
$ ghdl -a /common_pkg.vhd
./common_sim_pkg.vhd:2:14: file std_logic_1164.v93 has changed and must be reanalysed
```

common_pkg.vhd is:

```
library ieee;
use     ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package common_pkg is

  component block1 is
    port (
      port1  : out std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
      port2  : in    std_logic;
      port3  : in    std_logic;
      port4  : in    std_logic
      );
  end component;

  component block2 is
    port(
      port1 : in    std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
      port2 : in    std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
      port3 : in    std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
      port4 : in    std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
      port5 : in    std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
      port6 : in    std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
      port7 : in    std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
      port8 : in    std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);

      port9  :   out std_logic;
      port10 : in    std_logic;
      port11 : in    std_logic;
      port12 : in    std_logic
      );
  end component;

end package;
```

here's the ghdl version:

```
$ ghdl -v
GHDL 0.29.1 (20100301) [Sokcho edition]
 Compiled with GNAT Version: GPL 2009 (20090519)
 mcode code generator
Written by Tristan Gingold.

Copyright (C) 2003 - 2010 Tristan Gingold.
GHDL is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Something's either written to after install, prevented writing to during install, or corrupted the source for package std_logic_1164 or the library file (ending in .cf). Consider downloading a [newer version](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/releases) from the release number that's for Windows, use either mingw32 or 64 (the Windows mcode version is a 32 bit executable).

Comment: Yup, that's how I ended up solving it...downloading a newer version seems to fix the problem.  (Strangely the same binaries for ghdl work perfectly on a difference computer... which had me a little bit confused... perhaps some difference between different versions of windows...)

Comment: GHDL has come a LONG LONG way since 0.29... HIGHLY recommend an upgrade - https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl and info at https://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/